# Traversing Multiple JSON arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I was wondering if anyone could help.  Is there an easy and efficient way to traverse a JSON object if we are given the position of an error in that JSON object?  For example, say I hit a service with the JSON request below and it returns a bad request stating that the value in the field:
 **Cars[1]. Manufacturers [2].CarDetails[Doors]** 
is invalid (Last element of request – Toyota Hybrid with 100 doors).
Is there an easy way to traverse the request to pull the registration for that car given the error that is returned?  i.e. in the example below the value for doors on the Toyato Hybrid is invalid due to it being 100.  I want to be able to traverse my JSON request to pull back the registration of the vehicle with the issue.  In this example “Reg123” should be returned.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
"Cars": [{
    "Manufacturers": [{
            "Manufacturer": "Audi"
            "CarDetails": {
                "Model": "A4",
                "Doors": "3",
                "Registration": "abc123",
                "Transmission": "Automatic"
            }
        }, {
            "Manufacturer": "BMW",
            "CarDetails": {
                "Model": "X1",
                "Doors": "3",
                "Registration": "abc123",
                "Transmission": "Manual"
            }
        }, {
            "Manufacturer": "Renault"
            "CarDetails": {
                "Model": "Megane",
                "Doors": "3",
                "Registration": "abc123",
                "Transmission": "Automatic"
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    "Manufacturers": [{
            "Manufacturer": "Citroen"
            "CarDetails": {
                "Model": "C3",
                "Doors": "3",
                "Registration": "abc123",
                "Transmission": "Automatic"
            },
        }, {
            "Manufacturer": "Seat"
            "CarDetails": {
                "Model": "Leon",
                "Doors": "3",
                "Registration": "abc123",
                "Transmission": "Automatic"
            },
        }, {
            "Manufacturer": "Toyota",
            "CarDetails": {
                "Model": "Hybrid",
                "Doors": "100",
                "Registration": "Reg123",
                "Transmission": "Manual"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot, you can use

```
org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json
```

package and do something like this:

```
response.getJSONArray("Cars").getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("Manufacters").getJSONObject(2).getJSONObject("CarDetails").getString("Doors")
```

In addition to this line you must handle the JSONException exception

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately however I am not using spring boot.  Appreciate the response nonetheless.